# My xcode download keeps failing due to network error

Tags: xcode, networking, download

My xcode download keeps failing. It gets downloaded completely, but then says 'Failed - Network error'.

I have tried to download twice, switched off and on my mac. 
My internet connection is fine. 
I am downloading from developer.apple.com

Please suggest how to download Xcode. Mine is an older version of mac - version 10.10.5
so I am trying to download xcode_7.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Apple seems to be having a network issue.

In this answer, they show you how to download the file using curl, and how to resume an ongoing download using `-L -C -`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253269

Since it's "just" a network issue, you can simply retry until you have the full file. Or you can write a script:

```
until <curl command copied from chrome> -L -C -
do
  echo retrying
done
```

Hope it helps!